# Tensorflow : If an LSTM is 're-used' for new inputs, do its hidden states reset? In a single forward pass

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Question : I have an LSTM cell with variable scope name 'rnn' and assign it as 'scope'.

If I use scope.reuse_variables() within a graph, I know that the weights are reused for a new input X...

But if weights are reused, does the LSTM hidden state automatically reset? ... or do I have to explicitly reset the hidden state every time I call scope.reuse_variables()

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The hidden state is not saved with the model. It depends on the input data (which gets fed/queued/etc.).

Comment: does this mean that tensorfow maintains no internal memory for the hidden state in a forward pass ?

Comment: Ah. By "saved with the model" I mean they don't get saved in the checkpoint/metagraph/whatever gets written to persistent storage, and reusing variables does not (directly) reuse activations. While the graph is executing (a `session.run` call) intermediate activations are kept around in memory if they are going to be used to compute gradients (during training). If you don't request gradients, they will be discarded almost immediately. (This is just an effect of the more general "keep around inputs to nodes until they execute" strategy of dataflow programming.)